# How to get a kernel panic report

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-panic

I have a server on datapipe clould.  I am running ubuntu 12.04.  My servers have been crashing in the sense that mmonit marks the server with a red dot and I cant ssh into the machine.  This is due to chef-client.  So...I want to reboot a machine so I can get the panic report logs.  How do I get what I need so I can send to chef support?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that in case of a kernel panic, last valuable entries are not written to the logs, but are lost.

I recommend the introduce yourself to LKCD (Linux Kernel Crash Dump) project in http://lkcd.sourceforge.net/. Ubuntu has additionally its own set of instructions available: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe.

With this method the system basically boots from another kernel in case of a crash, saves the system state and reboots the system gracefully.

Best of luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the logs.. syslog, kern.log, dmesg in /var/log (default location) for errors. I would start there.

In addition to the system logs, I would also enable/increase the Chef-Client logging in the config file for the client. From [Chef-Docs](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Configuration+Settings#ChefConfigurationSettings-logoutput) you can enable Verbose logging and/or change the log_location to a file on the system for you to review.

The combination of the system & Chef logs should be a good start for troubleshooting and passing along to Chef support if needed.

As a side note, I found Chef's IRC chan to be quite helpful when I was getting started with their product.

Server: irc.freenode.net
Channel: #chef

Lastly, if those steps don't provide the information you need, you could look into using https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash or https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks to help gather data.